# My website si Blocked by google and warns the visitors that is Unsafe site

Tags: jquery

My website has been blocked by google, and it gives warnings to visitors that it is a Deceptive Site.

I checked the google transparency report to see the cause and It says that the problem is on the url: `https://caretech.co.tz/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4`

I do not know what to do to the jquery.js file to solve the problem.

I need help?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your site was hacked. I'm not going there, and would not recommend any 'lookers' unless you have a good 'sandbox' and infosec skills.

For the OP, I'd suggest checking your site for rouge code, files, etc. Check the source of your page to look for inserted code, or calls to external sites you don't expect. Look (via secure FTP) for unexpected files. Reinstall WP, update to latest version of everything, and check for rouge themes/plugins. Try changing the theme to one of the 'twenty' themes, and disable all plugins to see if you still get the Deceptive Site warning with a basic install.